# How do I access an <Any>-element in xslt?

Tags: c#, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xsd schema:

```
<Person>
 <Gender>
 <Any>
```

I have the following xml:

```
<Person>
 <Gender>Male</Gender>
 <Name>
  <firstName>Elon</firstName>
  <lastName>Musk</lastName>
</Name>
</Person>
```

I want to print the the text "Tesla" if the lastname is equal to "Musk".
I started with a template-match but I cannot access the Any-element.

Any good suggestions on how to access an -element in xslt?

I tried writing an template-match for this but I was not able to access the Any-element as expected.

```
<xsl:template match="/Person//* = 'Musk'">
    <text>Tesla</text>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Any` element in your XML, so you cannot access it.

If you want your template to match a `Person` whose `lastName` is "Musk", then do:

```
<xsl:template match="/Person[Name/lastName='Musk*']">
    <text>Tesla</text>
</xsl:template>
```

If you want your template to match a `Person` that has some descendant element with a value of "Musk", then do:

```
<xsl:template match="/Person[.//*='Musk']">
    <text>Tesla</text>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If i want to match an element that is named "TBD" but is specified as an <Any> element in the xsd schema, how do i manage that?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question. The XSD schema plays very little to no role here. If you know the element's name, match it by its name. If you don't, use `*` in its place.